# Hide FBFriendPickerViewController navbar when pushing onto UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Presenting an instance of `FBFriendPickerViewController` using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is pretty straightforward and the class seems like it is meant for that use case.  However, I want to push an instance of `FBFriendPickerViewController` onto an instance of `UINavigationController` using `pushViewController:animated:`.

Consider the following code as an example:

```
self.fbFriendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
self.fbFriendPickerController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
// configure stuff

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.fbFriendPickerController animated:YES];
```

However, the problem is that the instance of `FBFriendPickerViewController` already has a top navigation bar. When pushed onto a `UINavigationController`, this results in two top navigation bars stacked vertically, as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: double top nav bars]

One solution would be to hide the top nav bar of the `UINavigationController`, but that creates an awkward transition and there is no back button. Any thoughts on the best way to keep the `UINavigationController` top nav bar but the hide the `FBFriendPickerViewController` top nav bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking through the Facebook iOS SDK [source code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) on Github, I figured this out. `FBFriendPickerViewController` is a subclass of `FBViewController`. If you set the `doneButton` and `cancelButton` properties of any `FBViewController` to `nil`, `FBViewController` will remove the top navigation bar. As a result, the following code works:

```
self.fbFriendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
self.fbFriendPickerController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
self.fbFriendPickerController.doneButton = nil;
self.fbFriendPickerController.cancelButton = nil;
// configure stuff

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.fbFriendPickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Strange behavior. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: This helps me a lot because I also had the strange double bars but how do you handle the selection? There is no more 'Done' button..

Comment: I got it, added it programmatically and set the target to the 'facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed'.