# iOS Facebook FBFriendPicker two bars

Tags: ios, facebook, uinavigationbar, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the FBFriendPicker from the latest Facebook SDK and the code is working fine.

I'm opening the FriendPicker from a `UITableViewController` with a `NavigationBar` so I'm pushing the FriendPicker like this:

```
if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friend";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
        self.friendPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    }

    [self.friendPickerController loadData];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];
}
```

But the result of that now is this:

[image]

Is it possible to just have one bar like in this edited picture:

[image]

I tried hiding the `NavigationBar` but then the `UIToolBar` from the FriendPicker is behind the `Status Bar`. I also tried hiding the `UIToolbar` but then the `UIToolBar` is just black, the space is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FBFriendPickerViewController` uses a UINavigationController. You have two options:

1. Present the `FBFriendPickerViewController`, instead of pushing it into the navigation stack, like this:

   ```
   [self presentViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
2. I found another post on SE where someone solved the problem by hiding the buttons within the 'FBFriendPickerViewController' navigation controller before pushing it.

   [Hide FBFriendPickerViewController navbar when pushing onto UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428181/hide-fbfriendpickerviewcontroller-navbar-when-pushing-onto-uinavigationcontrolle)

Comment: I tried presenting but the NavigationBar from Facebook than is under the Status Bar. Your second option is in the right direction, it hides the Facebook NavigationBar but now I don't have a Done button anymore so I can't handle save the selection I've made.

Comment: I got it, I added the 'Done' button programmatically and set the action to the 'facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed'. Thanks a lot!